# Trying to get the last characters of dynamic string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongoose, cheerio

I am creating a news scraper app in JS that pulls in articles and their descriptions.

Below is the scraper; however, when pulling in the description, it also pulls in "read me" from the link as text. I would like to still pull in the excerpt but remove the Read More at the very end of it:

```
app.get("/scraper", function(req, res) {
  // Grabs the body of the html with request
  request("https://techcrunch.com/", function(error, response, html) {
    // Load into cheerio with $ as a shorthand selector
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    // Grabs the title, description, and link within the block-content class.
    $(".block-content").each(function(i, element) {

              // Save an empty result object
              var result = {};

              // Saves them as properties of the result object
              result.title = $(this).find(".post-title").children("a").text();
              result.link = $(this).find("a").children(".excerpt").attr("href");
              result.description =$(this).find(".excerpt").text();

              console.log(result);

        if (result.title && result.link && result.description) {

      // Creates a new entry using the article model

      var entry = new Article(result);

            // Saves that entry to the db
            entry.save(function(err, doc, next) {
              // Log any errors
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              }
            });
        }
});
```

This is the object; you can see the "read more" in the description.

```
{ title: 'Snapcart raises $10M to shed light on consumer spending in emerging markets',
  link: 'https://techcrunch.com/2017/10/25/snapcart-raises-10m/',
  description: 'Taking on a giant like the $15 billion research firm Nielsen is no easy task. But tucked away in Southeast Asia, Snapcart is a two-year old company that is making progress by shining light on the black box that is consumer spending in emerging markets. Read More' }
```

Comment: Please ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result.description =$(this).find(".excerpt").text().replace(' Read More', '');
```

Using [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) would remove the `Read More` from the string.